# How does Atheism work in D&D

Tags: dnd-5e, religions-and-deities

I know that in earlier editions of D&D Asmodeus worked to encourage atheism to gain souls.

Reading this fact got me wondering, how does an atheist (Someone who does not believe in the existence of a god) exist in a magical realm where people genuinely talk with the gods and the gods have an impact on peoples lives? Or is atheism in the D&D world more subtle, i.e. an atheist would accept that beings exist that have achieved great power but refuse to accept they are actually gods worthy of worship?

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? I'm concerned this will be read too much like a discussion prompt which usually gives responses that don't work within the site format.

Comment: This needs a setting specified (greyhawk, ebberon, etc), as what's true in one setting may not be true in another.

Comment: This may also be well received in world building SE, if you are looking for analysis outside of specific D&D game worlds. You would need to make your assumptions about how the world and deities work clear, or phrase it like "how to support exitsence of atheist characters in a fantasy world where divine magic works"

Comment: @Someone_Evil This kind of question belongs, I think, [on a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566).  Richard, have you reviewed the "Forces and Philosophies" section of the DMG?  (p. 10 - 13) You may be able to better focus this question once you take a look at that, and perhaps some of the Q&A here that address that element of the DMG may be helpful to you.  I'll leave the searching to you since you know what you are looking for. FWIW, I've been involved in a few productive threads on GiTP forums on this very topic.

Comment: [There are 14 returns on that key phrase](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdnd-5e%5D+forces+and+philosophies)

Comment: RE: "I know that in earlier editions of D&D Asmodeus worked to encourage atheism to gain souls." Can a source be cited for this?

Comment: @HeyICanChan At the very least, it is mentioned in the AD&D 2e book *Guide to Hell* on p. 50. "The furtherance of unbelief across the planes is Asmodeus’s primary goal. The more mortals who reject the power of divinity and the existence of an afterlife, the more souls that come to Nessus to feed him." At least in the Realms, this is no longer the case; his power there comes from his followers (since he has ascended to divinity).